# Storing the clicked URL Value in a variable from an Event Listener Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, dom

I have two buttons with the same class that I've added an Event Listener to:

I've added the event loop to return the value of the clicked item:

```js
const ctaClick = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-button');

for (let i = 0; i < ctaClick.length; i++) {
    ctaClick[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(ctaClick[i].getAttribute('href') + '?');
    });
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.cambrilearn.com/consultation"
   id="menu-button-2" target="_blank"
   class="menu-button" style="max-width: 1050px;">Consult</a>

<a href="https://www.cambrilearn.com/users/enrolment/role"
   id="menu-button" target="_blank"
   class="menu-button" style="max-width: 1050px;">Sign Up</a>
```

How do I store the clicked URL in a global variable?

Comment: Instead of writing in to the console just store it in the global variable?

Comment: My guess is you tried to set it to a variable already, but you have a different problem of reading it?

Comment: The `window` object is where global variables are stored — Pr77Pr77 posted an answer that suggests you set the value there, as `window.lastClickedButton = theHref;` but that isn't going to work. When you click the link you'll store the href, but then the link will be followed, going to a new page; the new page starts fresh, and `window.lastClickedButton` won't exist. You could store it in a cookie, or set it as a URL parameter so the next page has access to it... but really, the next page _is_ the target of the link and could just read its own URL.

Comment: @MarkBaijens, I had a bit of an "Aha!" moment last night in bed, so I added let ctaURL = ""; and then assigned the click value in the for loop. (I have no idea what I did yesterday afternoon, but it didn't work then).

Comment: @StephenP, it goes to a "www" subdomain, but I'm trying to read that clicked URL into another function that adds the UTM variables to the URL new URL when the user clicks it.

Comment: I am very, very new to JavaScript, so thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can do it like this:

```
const ctaClick = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-button');

for (let i = 0; i < ctaClick.length; i++)
    ctaClick[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.lastClickedButton = ctaClick[i].getAttribute('href');
});
```